# In Django, is there a built in filter which can mark these as safe?

Tags: python, django, templates, filter, django-templates

```
&gt; &lt;strong&gt;
```

HTML tags, and much more (these 3 are just examples)

Is there a filter that I actually render these in Django template, **but keep tags escaped**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't - if you mark something as `safe`, nothing will be escaped. If it's `unsafe`, everything will be. There isn't really way to say `this content is varying degrees of safe` - so if you want this, you'll have to write it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This should help but not bundled with Django:

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/295/